# I would like to know how to sort just letters that are in a function

Tags: javascript, regex, sorting, split

How do I use pure javascript to sort a group of letters like I've written below.
Do you I use a .match [a-zA-Z]?
or split? Or something else ??
For instance:

```
   sortGroupsOfLetters('x5*RnEM*BLL8nX@3');
   // Result should be something like: BLL5*RnEM*nX8x@3
   // Only the letters should be randomly sorted
```

this is what I have so far. It keeps on spitting out random letters without numbers like "*RnEM*BLLxnX@"

```
 function randomsort(a, b) { 
return Math.random()>.5 ? -1 : 1;
}
 var arrStr = 'x5*RnEM*BLL8nX@3';
 var res = arrStr.split(/[0-9]/gi).sort(randomsort,/[0-9]/gi); 
var randomStr = arrStr.split(/[0-9]/gi).sort(randomsort,/[0-9]/gi); 
 console.log(randomStr.join('')); // returns something like *RnEM*BLLxnX@"
```

I also created a function that keeps the numbers and symbols and replaces the letters with the first letter in the string (x5*xxxx*xxx8xx@3).

```
 function myFunction() {
  var arrStr = "x5*RnEM*BLL8nX@3"; 
  var letters = arrStr.split(/[0-9]/gi).sort(randomsort,/[0-9]/gi); 

  var res = arrStr.replace(/[a-z]/gi, letters[0]);

 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res  //displays something like x5*xxxx*xxx8xx@3
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic of how `x5*RnEM*BLL8nX@3` becomes `BLL5*RnEM*nX*x@3`.

Comment: @csm_dev: I call it magic. You know. stuff happens. I didn't get it as well anyway.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but it seems like you don't want letters sorted, but groups of letters. In your example you shuffle around `x`, `BLL`, `RnEM`, and `nX`, rather than individual letters themselves.

Comment: I'm guessing `*` and `@` are delimiters, and he doesn't want to sort the characters but rather the entire strings between the delims.

Comment: Also, the digit `8` has been deleted and an extra `*` has been added.

Comment: Sort criteria needs more clarification

Comment: the function should sort all the groups of letters within the string and return the result. So it could be RnEM5*BLL*x8nx@3

Comment: So please explain how in your example `8` got deleted and `*` got added. That is not sorting. Also, you don't say how they should be sorted. Randomly? If so then that is not sorting, it is shuffling.

Comment: The number 8 should not have gotten deleted. I apologize

Comment: @KhauriMcClain Yes I want to know how to sort the groups of letters

Comment: @KhauriMcClain I get how you go the arrays in the second two lines.

Comment: where are you getting the ((s,i)=>{return s + (b[i] || ( what is this shorthand for?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's other (better) ways to do this, but here's a solution.

First you separate letter groups and non letter groups into two different arrays. You then shuffle the letter groups in whatever way you feel like. Then you recombine the shuffled letter groups array with your other array.

In the example below I use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to create the two arrays, shuffle one, and then [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to put the entire thing back together.

```js
let str = 'x5*RnEM*BLL8nX@3'

// Get an array of letter groups
let a = str.match(/[a-z]+/gi)
// Get array of everything else in the string
let b = str.match(/[^a-z]+/gi)

// Shuffle the letter groups randomly
var j, x, i;
for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    x = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = x;
}

// Recombine the two arrays
let newstr = a.map((s,i)=>{return s + (b[i] || "")}).join("")

console.log(newstr)
```